# how to handle deserialized exceptions in case of batch mode

Tags: spring-kafka

how to handle deserialized exceptions in case of batch mode?
I am using spring kafka with spring boot -2.3.8 version.

Tried this option :

```
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
      ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory); 
    factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
    }
```

But it throws the exception :
caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The error handler must be an ErrorHandler, not org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler

**here are my application properties :**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = localhost:9093
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit = false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records = 10

spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.listener.type =  batch 
spring.kafka.ack.discard =  true
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode = MANUAL
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency = 1
idle-between-polls  = 120000
```

Answer (score 1):

It implies that the listener type is not being set properly.

I just copied your code and configuration to a new application and it works as expected.

Comment: setting this spring.kafka.listener.type =  batch  should work. but when i set it at container level like  factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setAckDiscarded(isAckDiscarded);  then working. is there any reason??

Comment: I can't explain it; no; as I said I simply copied your code/configuration as-is and it works for me. I was using Boot 2.4.4. but I just tried it with 2.3.8 (and 2.3.9) and it still works.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your help on time.